# Spring MVC - no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:annotation-drive'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Hi I am getting the following error.

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:annotation-drive'.
```

Here is my Spring context file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd"
       default-lazy-init="true">
<context:component-scan base-package="com.demo.myapp"/>

    <mvc:annotation-drive />
</beans>
```

I searched a lot, found so many solutions in Stackoverflow. But still I am not able to resolve this. What am I doing wrong here?

It's a maven project. Earlier it was not Spring-mvc, that Im trying to make as Spring-MVC project. I added the **spring-webmvc** dependency in pom file. version is `3.1.3.RELEASE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<mvc:annotation-driven />` instead of

```
<mvc:annotation-drive />
```